# How to find my UserID in Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, support, users

How can I find my UserID on Stack Overflow? I tried checking in my profile but I can't find one.

Any ideas where to find it?

Comment: I'm amazed about how people didn't know where to find userid...

Comment: @nicael - FYI it is not present in front of my eyes but some where in **Address bar**

Comment: But it is the axiom!!! fundamental truth!!!

Comment: And in the search bar, as pointed out :p You're apparently not a `GET` fan. I don't think it's a bad question though, not at all.

Comment: @nicael May be but still i can't conclude that a **numeric value** in address bar is my userid

Comment: @keyser - Thanks for holding my back :D

Comment: @NoDisplayName Pro tip: If you remove your name from the address and load that page, you'll still get your profile. That's one way to "prove" that it's your user ID (or at least profile ID, but let's assume stackoverflow knows what they're doing :p)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

It's the number in the middle of [your profile URL](//stackoverflow.com/users/current),

```
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3349551/nodisplayname
------------------------------------^^^^^^^
```

This number also appears in links to your answers, and to any link you share, which helps track who shared the link (which is how you get the Publicist badge)

This is the share link for this meta question. The `541091` is my ID:

```
 http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281254/541091
 ---------------------------------------^^^^^^ Me!
```

That identifier differs across Stack Exchange sites. You can see all your accounts in one place by viewing your profile on http://stackexchange.com. Mouse over the links to your accounts to find your ID on each.

I recommend committing your Stack Overflow id to memory, so you can easily search for your own stuff by including `user:3349551` in your search queries, or to substitute it in user-specific queries in the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You don't need to remember your own user id for searches. You can use `user:me` instead of the numerical user id.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Nice! I have used the ID(without user:) many times in Google searches too though

Comment: It's also useful to memorize it for use in the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @AstroCB Very true. That's actually the most common case where I use it. I don't write queries myself, but I sometimes try them when somebody posts about queries for interesting statistics.

Answer (score 38):

Looking at the URL is one option. But it is in the profile as well. When you're on your profile page, check out the Search box in the top-right corner:

[image]

The circled number is your user id.